# Remove the final newline (\n) from a shell pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, newline, zsh

I have:

```
alias pbcopy='xclip -selection clipboard -in'
```

This allows me to do things like `date | pbcopy`, to get the date in the clipboard.

However, I also get a newline character at the end of the date which needs to be manually removed after pasting.

How can I remove the final newline (and only the final newline) from a pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Pipe through:

```
sed -z '$ s/\n$//'
```

`sed` won't add a `\0` to then end of the stream if the delimiter is set to `NUL` via `-z`, whereas to create a POSIX text file (defined to end in a `\n`), it will always output a final `\n` without `-z`.

Eg:

```
$ { echo foo; echo bar; } | sed -z '$ s/\n$//'; echo tender
foo
bartender
```

And to prove no `NUL` added:

```
$ { echo foo; echo bar; } | sed -z '$ s/\n$//' | xxd
00000000: 666f 6f0a 6261 72                        foo.bar
```

---

To remove multiple trailing newlines, pipe through:

```
sed -Ez '$ s/\n+$//'
```